# What are "consecutive input pulses"?

Tags: digital-logic, state-machines

I am stuck on a homework problem that I have difficult time understanding:

> Draw the state diagram of the circuit described below, with detailed
>   explanations:
>
> A detection circuit has two inputs, x1 and x2, such that an output z
>   will become 1 as soon as 4 consecutive input pulses are received and
>   the 4-bit sequence contained at least two x1 pulses.  Assume the
>   sequences consisting x1 and x2 may not overlap.

Could anyone clarify this question for me? Does a "pulse" by definition means when an input goes from 0 to 1, then to 0?  When it says "4 consecutive input pulses" does it mean for both inputs, x1 and x2?  I am not getting the whole picture together...

Comment: A state machine periodically decides what its next state should be (typically at the rising edge of a system clock). Given that this is an introductory homework problem about designing a statechart (state diagram), I would interpret "4 consecutive pulses" as meaning that on four consecutive system clock edges, the input was 1. I think what they're looking for is, say after you've counted N consecutive pulses, how do you decide next state -- N+1 consecutive pulses or back to zero? Your definition of pulse is correct, I think it's just not relevant to this homework exercise.

Comment: And when in doubt, if you can't ask the instructor or TA, then at least document the assumption that you're making.

Answer (score 1):

The use of the word "consecutive" might be a bit confusing.

The condition means that the output goes active after four consecutive pulses, of which at least two are on x1. In other words, it doesn't simply need to see two pulses on x1, there have to be two x1 pulses in the last 4 pulses.

Thus the sequence:

X1 X2 X2 X2 X1

contains 2 X1 pulses, but not within 4 consecutive pulses, whereas

X1 X2 X2 X1 contains 2 X1 pulses within 4 consecutive pulses.

Comment: Thank you for reply.  So this is under an assumption that x1 and x2 does not equal 0 or 1 at same time?

Comment: It would be valid to assume he means positive pulses, so that X1 and X2 can both be 0, but only one can be '1' at any time (non-overlapping) ... and state that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I interpret the question as a "pulse" being a 0-1-0 sequence on one input.

As for "consecutive", think of that as meaning "in a row", or "the last N pulses".

You are supposed to come up with a diagram for a machine that asserts its output when the last 4 pulses in a row contained at least two pulses on X1.  For example, the sequence

X2 X2 X1 X2

should not trigger the output, whereas

X1 X2 X1 X2

should.